# How do I include a returned object in another javascript file?

Tags: node.js, include

I have a routes.js file that looks like this.

```
return {
  "GET" : {
    "/" : renderHomePage
  },
  "POST" : {
    "/ajax/addUser" : addUser
  }
}
```

I am trying to include it in the main create server script so that I can access it directly inside the variable to call the functions.

```
var routes = require("routes.js");
    var internalFunction = routes.GET["/"];
        internalFunction();
```

It isn't working but I was wondering how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of using "include",
try this:

```
var routes = require("routes.js");
```

Comment: hi sorry that was a typo just in the example code, not in the real application.